# Facebook API Library destroying session/cookie data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have on my `generic sign in page` a button that **allows a user to log in via facebook.** Also, i have the following code just prior to the user clicking the button so i can pass a redirect url to the callback after oauth2 authorization and redirect the logged in user somewhere.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$url=$helper->getLoginUrl("https://example.com/fblogin/callback");
$_SESSION['redirect']='somehurl';
setcookie("redirect","example.com");
header("Location: $url&scope=email");
```

Then I have

In my callback I have

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['redirect']); //null
var_dump($_COOKIE['redirect']); // null
```

**I dont understand why but facebook is destroying my cookie and session data**. Im using version 2.10

Comment: It's literally not possible for Facebook to destroy your session or cookie data. This is an impossibility because they don't have access to this data. They don't have access to your server and they absolutely cannot modify this data in any modern browser with basic security features in place. The problem is your code itself. Perhaps, for instance, you perform a redirect prior to calling `session_start()`. We can only speculate as to where your code might be failing, but it's absolutely your code that is failing. Facebook has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Small correction: If you're using their SDK, then it's possible that there's something occurring there with their code. I sincerely doubt that they're destroying your data, however. More likely is that your workflow is failing somewhere, where you're either failing to do something or you're doing things in the wrong order. Again, we can only speculate given the small amount of information we've been given.

Comment: check update question

Comment: furthermore this only happens with facebook.

Comment: Please check your session ID and ensure that it remains persistent across requests. If it changes, you'll want to ensure that no server resources are being loaded in which `session_start()` is missing from the beginning of the script. If it's remains persistent, we can proceed further with debugging efforts.

Comment: Sounds good ill look into this in a few